# ar_track_alvar image topic to point cloud

Tags: ros, image, pointcloud, ar-track-alvar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!
This is my first time using AR Tags in ROS.
I already had my camera with /image_raw and /camera_info topics published.
However, when I ran "roslaunch ar_track_alvar pr2_indiv.launch"

there was an error saying:
"Could not process inbound connection: topic types do not match: [sensor_msgs/PointCloud2] vs [sensor_msgs/Image]"

I believe my sensor_msgs/Image topic already correct, since I can visualize them in rviz and in image_view.
Is this a bug? since in the instructions it is clearly stated that Image topic is used...

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150756/ar_track_alvar-image-topic-to-point-cloud/) by [Dipta](https://answers.ros.org/users/14186/dipta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using ar_track_alvar with a normal camera (not with a Kinect) use the pr2_indiv_no_kinect.launch launch-file.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4